# how to pass pass parameter to get value from xml request.get python

Tags: python, parameters, web-scraping

How can I pass parameter into function using request.get()

so here's my original code

```
def get_xml():
    xml = requests.get("http://charts.com/charts/101.xml").text
    return xml
print get_xml()
```

This code above would get what I need, but how can I replace "101" with x .
I was trying to replace my address with url variable but I got typeError . please advice.

```
def get_xml(x):

    url = "http://charts.com/charts/" + x + ".xml"
    xml = requests.get(url).text
    return xml

print get_xml(101)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an strongly typed language. That means it doesn't know how to add and integer and an string:

```
>>> "5" + 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

and in your case, `101` is an int.

You can try calling the `get_xml` function with an string as the argument:

```
print get_xml("101")
```

Or convert (cast) the parameter (inside the function) to string before trying to concatenate (this second option is probably better, since then your function will work fine with `x` being either an `int` or an `str`, and won't depend on the *good will* of the programmer calling the `get_xml` function):

```
url = "http://charts.com/charts/" + str(x) + ".xml"
```

or:

```
url = "http://charts.com/charts/%s.xml" % x
```

(for that last one, check [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting))

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_xml(x):    
    url = "http://charts.com/charts/%s.xml" % x
    xml = requests.get(url).text
    return xml

print get_xml(101)
```

Comment: Thanks , but it didn't work. It didn't even give me the error msg  url = "http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/%s.xml"

Answer (score 1):

You can try using format, as in the below example:

```
def get_xml(x):

    url = "http://charts.com/charts/{}.xml".format(x)
    xml = requests.get(url).text
    return xml

print get_xml(101)
```

EDIT: For a more thorough explanation on *format*, please see the following [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 1):

def get_xml(x):

```
url = "http://charts.com/charts/" + x + ".xml"
xml = requests.get(url).text
return xml
```

print get_xml("101")

This is likely what your modified code should look like.  I think the code thinks you're trying to add text and numbers together